# Exponential function inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How can you show that $$(1-\frac{1}{n})^r \leq e^{-r/n}\ ?$$

I'm not really too sure how to do it.

Comment: can you tell us something about the variables?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: what kind of numbers are $$r,n$$?

Comment: Tell us whether $n$ is a natural number or not and so on.

Comment: from where does this inequality come?.

Comment: Oh of course. Both $r$ and $n$ are natural numbers ($\neq 0$).

Answer (score 2):

I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) that the sequence $e_n$, given by $e_n=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing.  Recalling that $\lim_{n\to \infty}e_n=e^{-1}$ we have

$$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n<e^{-1} \tag 1$$

whence raising both sides of $(1)$ to the $r/n$, where $r\in \mathbb{N}$, power yields the coveted inequality

$$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^r<e^{-r/r}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 0):

taking the logarithm on both sides we obtain
$$r\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)<-\frac{r}{n}$$
if $$r>0$$ then we can divide by $$r$$ and we get $$\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)<-\frac{1}{n}$$ multipliying by $-1$ we get $$-\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n>1$$
can you finish this?